# Primeng p-table: how to reset custom filters? Calling reset() resets the table but the value of my filters remains unchanged

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

How can I reset all of the column filters? Calling reset() seems to reset the table but all the fields of the filters remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the input values to the table's filters, like this:

```
<input type="search" (input)="table.filter($event.target.value, 'FieldName', 'contains')" [value]="table.filters['FieldName']?.value" />
```

Notice the `[value]` binding.

Comment: Hey @SZH How to do the same for dropdown ?
`<p-dropdown [options]="sites" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" 
                                            (onChange)="tt.filter($event.value, 'NAME', 'equals')">
                                        </p-dropdown>`

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out how to get this working with a dropdown?